# How to solve React Native Google map probelm "ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':react-native-maps@release/compileClasspath' "?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

In my **react-native** project, I have upgraded the react-native version from **0.57.8 to 0.59.1**. I had some dependencies to import google map in my project.

Here's the dependency added in my **package.json** file for integrating **google map**-

> "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0"

Here's my **app level gradle file** configuration-

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXX"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 101
        versionName "2.0.5"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
 implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
  }

 implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }


    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')

  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
         implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"



    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar' 
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
}


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"



task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here's the set up of my **project level gradle file**-

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"


    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
         maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Now, when I build my project, it shows the following error-

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':react-native-maps@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0. Show Details Affected
>   Modules: react-native-maps

So, I need a solution to solve this problem to support all the required dependency in this react native project.

Comment: Could you try add `implementation  com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0` in  dependencies??

Comment: It doesn't work.